# How do I create an Authorization token with the "upn"/"unique_name" (emailId of user) as part of the claim, for my API Integration testcases

Tags: c#, authorization, azure-active-directory

I want to run my API testcases as part of which I'm generating the Authorization token. Earlier, the Application endpoints required the UserEmailId to be passed as a query string, but now it has been modified to read the UserEmailId from Authorization token. I want to modify my GenerateAuthToken method to include EmailId as part of the generated Auth token.

I referred to the documentation in,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/claims

I have tried to pass the UserEmailId using UserAssertion, as below.

```
string authorityUrl = string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}", authority);
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUrl, false);
        ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(this.utils.GetClientId(), this.utils.GetClientSecret());
        UserAssertion userAssertion = new UserAssertion("demoUser@tenant1.onmicrosoft.com");
        AuthenticationResult authResult = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(this.resource, clientCredential, userAssertion).Result;
```

but i get the below exception,
AdalServiceException: AADSTS50027: JWT token is invalid or malformed.

### Expected: I want the UserEmail Id to be part of the claim, currently it is not.

```
{
  "aud": "1bbc71b1-56b3-404c-8961-76ed5f603fab",
  "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/e46fc01a-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/v2.0",
  "iat": 1549957732,
  "nbf": 1549957732,
  "exp": 1549961632,
  "aio": "42JgYGiUKZN6pn6WdbPPN9bLIW8ZAA==",
  "azp": "1bbc71b1-56b3-404c-8961-76ed5f603fab",
  "azpacr": "1",
  "tid": "e46fc01a-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "uti": "rbpCCAb6TEuNRRaen_0DAA",
  "ver": "2.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the very few cases where I have found the ROPC flow to be usable.
ADAL does not offer an overload for it (mainly so people don't abuse this flow I guess), so you'll have to make the call manually.
Here is an example:

```
string tokenUrl = _authority + "oauth2/token";
var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, tokenUrl)
{
    Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["grant_type"] = "password",
        ["client_id"] = "your-clientid",
        ["client_secret"] = "your-clientsecret",
        ["resource"] = "resource-uri-or-client-id-of-api",
        ["username"] = "your-username",
        ["password"] = "your-password"
    })
};

HttpResponseMessage res = await _client.SendAsync(req);

string json = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
AadTokenResponse tokenResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AadTokenResponse>(json);
```

The response class here is pretty simple:

```
public class AadTokenResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("access_token")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
}
```

Note this'll only work if the user does not have MFA, does not require authentication with ADFS etc.
You should not use this flow against a production tenant, only a test user in a test tenant.
You are essentially acquiring an access token to call the API on behalf of the user without showing a login screen.
This should not be used to skip the login screen in apps.
However, I have found it very useful for this kind of API testing.